# Unable to deploy NodeJS and React Application on Azure Web App

Tags: reactjs, node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-digital-twins

I am working on the a NodeJS and React application, getting generated from the below command:
npm install @microsoft/iot-cardboard-js@beta.

Detailed Link: https://github.com/microsoft/iot-cardboard-js/wiki/Embedding-3D-Scenes

When I deploy the application on the Azure Web App (OS: Linux), it throws different erors everytime:

1. 3:34:01 PM DigitaltwinsViewer-Linux: Creating an optimized production build...
   3:47:26 PM: Error: :( Application ErrorIf you are the application administrator, you can access the <a style="color: grey"href="https://digitaltwinsviewer-linux.scm.azurewebsites.net/detectors">diagnostic resources.
2. The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.

The application is being deployed with the below deployment configuration:
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true

**Project Structure:**

[image]

I tried to deploy the application on the Azure Web App (with Linux OS and Windows OS), but it takes long time and finally azure throws error.

I am trying to deploy from the Visual Studio Code with Azue Extension with below deployment configuration:
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true

Is there anything I am missing or need to make changes to make the deployment successful?

Comment: Are you deploying using Azure DevOps pipeline? If so, please share your yaml configuration. Please add the variable `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in your pipeline. After that trigger a new pipeline to capture and share error in the debug logs.  About how to deploy a web app in Azure, see [Deploy a Node.js web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode) for the detailed info.

Comment: No, I am trying to deploy directly from the Visual Studio Code using the Azure extension.

Comment: @RaveendraSharma, can you provide your code or repository link if you have your code in GitHub(if you don't have any sensitive information).

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are deploying the application with all the required files.
- Check if the `NodeJs` version in Azure App Service is compatible with the version of `@microsoft/iot-cardboard-js@beta`.
- Remove `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` setting and try deploying again.
- Run `npm run build` or `npm start` before deploying the application.
- If still issue persists, along with `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`, try enabling the Oryx build by adding the setting  `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD= true` in `App Service=>Environment Variables=>App Settings`.
- Create a new `Azure App Service` in any other `region` and deploy your application using other deployment method like CLI with the command `az webapp up --name <webapp_name>`.

> 1. The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called  `kill -9`  on the process.

- This could be due to the memory issues, Add setting`"WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_MEMORY_LIMIT"="512MB"`.

**I have created a simple `ReactJs and NodeJs` application with the command `npx create-react-app <project_name> --template iot-cardboard-js`:**

[image]
[image]

- Deployed to Azure App Service successfully via `visual studio code` and could access the application without any issues.

[image]

**References:**

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/cra-template-iot-cardboard-js